# Select Multiple Checkboxes By Cntrl + Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a form which has many checkbox elements lined up in rows. I would like to implement a function that allows a user to hold Cntrl, then select a checkbox and have every box either:

**A) Become checked is there is no initial box checked**
**B) Become checked from the closest checked box**

Is this possible? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this could help you .

The code is for `shift+key`

```
// Usage: $form.find('input[type="checkbox"]').shiftSelectable();
// replace input[type="checkbox"] with the selector to match your list of checkboxes

$.fn.shiftSelectable = function() {
var lastChecked,
    $boxes = this;

$boxes.click(function(evt) {
    if(!lastChecked) {
        lastChecked = this;
        return;
    }

    if(evt.shiftKey) {
        var start = $boxes.index(this),
            end = $boxes.index(lastChecked);
        $boxes.slice(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end) + 1)
            .attr('checked', lastChecked.checked)
            .trigger('change');
    }

    lastChecked = this;
});
```

};

credits : [jQuery plugin for shift + click to select multiple checkboxes](https://gist.github.com/DelvarWorld/3784055)